# Computed property reactive to window.innerwidth in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Basically, what I need is a computed property that returns `true` when the `window.innerwidth` is equal or lower than 768px and `false` when it's higher than 768px.

What I did:

```
computed: {
  isMobile() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
      return true
    } 
    return false
  }
}
```

But that computes that property only once, and if I resize the window later, it doesn't react to that change. What can I do?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add an eventlistener to the window like so:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() { return { windowWidth: window.innerWidth } },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth
      console.log(this.isMobile)
    })
  },
  computed: {
    isMobile() {
      return this.windowWidth <= 768
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: i also setted the value of the variable on mounted apart of adding the eventListener, so at the start windowWidth is not zero and the computed returns an incorrect value.

Comment: As a rule, shouldn't you always remove eventlisteners in beforeDestroy()?

Comment: Getting 'window is undefined' when instantiated in the data like this.

Comment: You'll need to assign `this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth` inside of the mounted function (before the event listener) to avoid the 'window is undefined' error

Comment: I made exactly like this but in mixin and my isMobile computed prop doesn't updating(

Answer (score 3):

Computed properties are only updated when their depedencies change, therefore here isMobile won't be reactive.

Answer (score 3):

An other possibily is to use Vuetify:

```
computed: {
  isMobile() {
    return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown
  },
},
```

src: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service-object

Comment: I was already using Vuetify but didn't know this was a feature. Nice tip!