# Vue.js Element-UI el-table: how to show or hide table column according to the screen width

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-component

My code to create a table is:

```
<el-table :data="tableData" empty-text="Sem dados a exibir :( " v-if="window.width > 855">
  <el-table-column
   v-for="column in tableColumnsMd"
   :key="column.label"
   :min-width="column.minWidth"
   :prop="column.prop"
   :label="column.label"
  >
</el-table-column>
```

JS:

```
data() {
      return {
        tableColumnsMd: [
          {
            prop: "nome",
            label: "Nome",
            minWidth: 150,
            show:true,
          },
          {
            prop: "estado",
            label: "Estado",
            minWidth: 200,
            show:false,
          },
          {
            prop: "dataCadastro",
            label: "Cadastro",
            minWidth: 150,
            show:false,
          },
          {
            prop: "idConta",
            label: "Conta",
            minWidth: 100,
            show:false,
          },
        ],
        //dados sincronizados com a tabela
        tableData: [],
      };
    },
```

There are 4 column in total .

I would like to: if screen width < 853px, then only show the first 3 column, or show the first and the last column, for example.

Thank u

Comment: You can achieve this by dynamically assign `true/false` in a `show` property based on the screen width in your script code and then bind the data into the template.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

1. Create a computed property which performs your check:

```
computed: {
 shouldShowCols() {
   return window.innerWidth > 853
 }
}
```

Then use this in your template markup either with `v-show` (renders anyways, but will hide the element via inline style `display: none` on it if expression is false) or `v-if`.

For example:

```
<el-table :data="tableData" empty-text="Sem dados a exibir :( " v-if="shouldShowCols">
  <el-table-column
   v-for="column in tableColumnsMd"
   :key="column.label"
   :min-width="column.minWidth"
   :prop="column.prop"
   :label="column.label"
  >
</el-table-column>
```

**Edit**

Since this should be reactive in order to work, you should attach an event listener like explained here:

[Computed property reactive to window.innerwidth in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490561/computed-property-reactive-to-window-innerwidth-in-vuejs)

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but as the "v-if" is in <el-table>, will hide the whole table and not just the columns.

Comment: Ah yeah I see. Then you should put the `v-if` on the `<el-table-col>`. But keep in mind that the`v-for` should have its own template tag. Example: `<template v-for="todo in todos">   
  <li v-if="!todo.isComplete">
     {{ todo.name }}   
  </li> 
</template> `. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48933606/v-for-and-v-if-not-working-together-in-vue-js